# How to attach a child window in firefox with parent window in C# code using WatiN

Tags: c#, watin

I want to attach a child window with parent window of firefox browser.  AttachToIE attaches IE child window to IE parent window.  Is there any method in WatiN.Core for firefox?  Anybody knows?

Answer (score 0):

The WatiN 2.0 Beta (version 2.0.10.928) does not support an AttachTo method for Firefox. However it is supported in the latest trunk revision in subversion. This includes support in the generic Browser class. i.e. Browser.AttachTo.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Watin (RC1) supports `FireFox.AttachTo()` method.